# Why does console.log(this) in node return an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I ran console.log(this) in node it returns empty object

```
console.log(this)             // return { }
```

But when I used IIFE in node

```
(function printThisObject(){
   console.log(this);         // return the global object
})();
```

Can someone explain this to me ?

Comment: Related: [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because NodeJS runs your code in a *module*, and `this` references the object it creates for your module's exports (which is also the `exports` property on the `module` variable it provides you). (As they don't really mention that in [the module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), I suspect using it is probably not a great idea — use `exports` instead.)

But your code calling the IIFE calls it with `this` referring to the global object, because in loose (non-strict) mode, calling a normal function not through an object property calls it with `this` set to the global object. (In strict mode, `this` would be `undefined` there.)

Comment: Note, if you run without a module it does print contents of `global`. Example: `node -e 'console.log(this)'`.

Comment: @DanLowe: Learn something new every day, I didn't realize immediate code was run at global scope, outside of a module. But you're right, it is (and thus `this` refers to the global object).